# Combine GetType with Cast to convert List<IInterface> to List<Type>

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I am aware of the antipatern nature of this request, but maybe there is a better alternative.

**In Brief**

I have `List<IBaseEntity>` and want to convert to `List<ActualEntity>`. Though ActualEntity needs to come from reflection of what IBaseEntity actually is. It is one of 50+ potential classes

so something like this:

```
public void Install(List<IBaseEntity> list)
{
    var type = list.First().GetType();
    var typedList = list.Cast<?>(?).ToList()
    ThirdPartyClass.Install( typedList )
}
```

Just unsure how to get the `type` into the `Cast`

**Details of Why**

The Install method MUST be the concrete type as a 3rd party component is using that type to link to the a DbSet in EF. So the list of BaseEntity won't work. It throws an exception about not finding `DbSet<IBaseEntity>`. It needs to be `DbSet<ConcreteClass>`

I guarantee that IBaseEntity will ALWAYS be the same concrete class, but the method is called many times with each entity in the application. So doing a usual cast by specifying each concrete type won't be practical.

EF is OK with adding DbContext.AddRange(list)  and it seems to work out what IBaseEntity actually is and use the correct mapping.

Thanks in advance

** Update **
It was suggested that the calling method would know the type, unfortunately it is a little more complex, so let me explain that point.

There is a `BaseSampleData<TEntity> : ISampleDataBuilder` class which handles creating sample data, it maintains a list of primary keys of other entities etc.

Now the sticking point is a factory which assembles them

```
public class ProjectASampleDataFactory
{
    public class List<ISampleDataBuilder> GetBuilders(){
        return new List<ISampleDataBuilder> {
            new UserSampleData(), // ISampleDataBuilder<User>
            new BlogsSampleData(), // ISampleDataBuilder<Blogs>
            etc...
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is I need to have a List<ISampleData> which is the list of builders, but they don't intrinsically know of their type. So the caller actually doesn't know. the ??? are all different (see comments of above code block)

So I get a list which every entity follows, but although it is a List we just don't know which ActualEntity it is.

Comment: Would something like `public void Install<T>(List<IBaseEntity> list) where T : IBaseEntity` work here?

Comment: @stuartd I think the point is that `ThirdPartyClass.Install` has a `List<ActualEntity>` as parameter.

Comment: Yes @Dominik, but wouldn't this mean a `Cast<T>()` call would be possible before pasing the parameters to the third party?

Comment: Install is List<T> but T needs to be the ActualClass (which is the same as the DbSet<ActualClass> I have no control over this method.

MyListOfIBaseEntity.First().GetType() somehow needs to be fed into the <T> of cast

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method  is the answer... someone may even write out how to call `Cast<T>` for you... also I'd not count on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you control the caller of this method? Since the caller probably already knows what type it is processing, can you force them to provide the concrete type?

```cs
public void Install<T>(IEnumerable<IBaseEntity> list) where T:IBaseEntity
    => ThirdPartyClass.Install( list.Cast<T>().ToList() );
```

Even if you can't change the call site, you can call your method via reflection;

```cs
public void Install(List<IBaseEntity> list)
{
    var type = list.First().GetType();
    new Action<IEnumerable<IBaseEntity>>(Install<IBaseEntity>)
        .Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
        .MakeGenericMethod(type)
        .Invoke(this, new object[] { list });
}
```

Comment: I like this...I think I would like this more if you moved the Generic Install method inside of the Install method body...

Comment: You could do that, but I would prefer to mark the non-generic method Obsolete to suggest  callers move to calling the generic version instead, since the caller is likely to already know the correct type.

Comment: Just tried it with LinqPad, seems to require C#8 to work, since I would need to define it as a static void in order to get around the Lambda capture problem. I am posting my version that includes pattern matching to ensure list is not empty...

Comment: I added some notes as to why I cannot change the calling method, hope it makes sense. I tried your second option, and it looks promising. It's not working 100%, but I am checking if that is the library not updating the IDs of what it is installing, or the way I am calling it.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. Ultimately, you've answered the question and I'll look at the primary key return issue and ask separately if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Jeremy Lakeman for the idea to access the MethodInfo via an Action delegate.

Note, this requires C#8 to work, as it requires static lambdas to work.

```
public void Install(List<IBaseEntity> list)
{
    if (!(list.FirstOrDefault() is {} first))
        return;
        
    static void InstallImpl<T>(List<IBaseEntity> list) where T : IBaseEntity
    {
        ThirdPartyClass.Install<T>(list.OfType<T>().ToList());
    }
    
    new Action<List<IBaseEntity>>(InstallImpl<IBaseEntity>)
        .Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
        .MakeGenericMethod(first.GetType())
        .Invoke(null, new[] {list});
}
```

Comment: I think you meant "static local function", and you could always make it a normal function for C#<8

Comment: @Charlieface you need to then pass in the capture to the local function, which is quite impossible...

Comment: I don't get it, there is no capture here, it's just a normal parameter

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider using a non generic `List` in your method in order to avoid passing e.g. a `List<object>` into a method that uses `List<string>`.

The keyword `dynamic` is made for exactly cases like this.

Have a look at this sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var objectList = new List<int>();
    objectList.Add(1);
    YourMethod(objectList);
}

static void YourMethod(IList objects)
{
    dynamic dynamicObjects = objects;
    FrameworkMethod(dynamicObjects);
}

static int FrameworkMethod(IList<int> typedList)
{
    return typedList.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the Framework method in your example is IList<T> and using IList results in the error of not being able to identity what T is

Comment: @Simon you could of course also use `List<T>` instead of `IList<T>`